# How to find derivative and directional derivative of this map

Tags: real-analysis

This question was asked in my quiz( Multivariable analysis) and I am having a hard time figuring it out:

> Consider the map $f: M(n,\mathbb{R})\to M(n,\mathbb{R})$ which satisfies $f([A]_{ij})= ({[A]_{ij}})^2$, where $[A]_{ij}$ denotes the ij th entry of matrix  A. Then prove that:(a)The direction derivative of function f along the direction H is a matrix whose ij th entry is $2 [A]_{ij} .[H]_{ij}$. (b) The derivative of  f is represented by an $n^2 \times n^2$ diagonal  matrix wrt to standard basis on $M(n,\mathbb{R})$.

I found the directional derivative using definition and found it to be equal to AH +HA.

Also, I found derivative to be equal to AH+HA which is a $n\times n $ matrix, not necessarily diagonal.

So, both  my answers are wrong. I tried them today 2nd time ( 1st time in quiz). So, I think I need help in this.

Comment: what exactly is $f$ supposed to satisfy? The sentence is not complete there. (the person who upvoted already despite of this lack of information should know :-D)

Comment: @Thomas I am really sorry, It was a typo. Edited it.

Comment: It would work if the function was $f([A]_{ij}) = ([A]_{ij}^2)$. It could be a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write down the definitions.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\partial_H f(A) & := \lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(A+tH)-f(A)}{t}\\
& = \lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{[A+tH]_{ij}^2-[A]_{ij}^2}{t}\\
& = \lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{ 2 t[A]_{ij}[H]_{ij} +t^2[H]_{ij}^2}{t}(*)\\
& = 2[A]_{ij}[H]_{ij}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
My guess is that your issue was in the ($*$) step. Notice that the squaring is happening entry by entry, so *matrix product* never enters the picture.

If we identify $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ as
$$
A"="([A]_{11},\ldots, [A]_{1n},[A]_{21},\ldots, [A]_{2n},[A]_{31},\ldots, [
A]_{nn}),
$$
then we can write $$f=(f_1,\ldots f_{n^2})= ([f]_{11},\ldots, [f]_{1n}, [f]_{21}, \ldots, [f]_{nn}).$$ The derivative of this map at $A$ is a linear map $Df(A): \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, which can be written as an $n^2\times n^2$ matrix, whose $k$-th row is given by the gradient of $f_k$. For this notice that if $f_k=[f]_{ij}$ for some $1\leq i,j\leq n$, then
$$
\partial_{lm} f_k(A) = \partial_{lm} [A]_{ij}^2 = \delta_{li}\delta_{mj} 2[A]_{ij},
$$
where $\partial_{lm}$ denotes the directional derivative in the direction of the matrix having only a 1 in the $lm$ entry, and zero everywhere else. $\delta$ denotes the Kronecker delta. This gives that the Jacobian matrix (with the above identification of the matrix space) is represented by a diagonal matrix (where you write down 2 times the matrix entries, read row by row, left to right, along the diagonal).

Comment: In (b) how does derivative of this map  which is Df(A) can be written as $n^2 \times n^2 $ matrix?

Comment: @No-One: Remember that the derivative of a map $g:\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}^q$ at a point $x\in \mathbb{R}^p$ can be written as a $q\times p$ matrix whose rows are the gradients of the coordinates of $g$. In our case $p=q=n^2$.

Comment: How did you wrote $\delta_{lm} {[A]_{ij}}^2 =$$ \delta_{li} $$\delta_{mj} 2$$ {[A]_{ij}}$?

Comment: $\partial_{lm}[A]_{ij}^2$ is the derivative with respect to the $lm$ entry of the matrix. Since all the entries are independent, it's zero unless $ij$ is exactly the same as $lm$, and this is how the Kronecker delta pops up.

Comment: I understood how it will be zero unless ij is exactly same as lm but how you wrote $\delta_{lm} {[A]_{ij}}^2 =\delta_{li} \delta_{mj} 2[A]_{ij}?  why exactly there should be   li and mj in subscript?

Comment: @No-One: Because the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) will give you exactly this property of being only non-zero when $l=i$ and $m=j$ (that's why you multiply the deltas).